# AWS Elasticsearch showing cluster health yellow, how should I fix it?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am using AWS Elasticsearch. My cluster status is yellow for past 48 hours on the recommendation provided here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-handling-errors.html

I've updated my nodes to be 15 data and it has 3 master nodes.

Even though it has more spaces for around 60 Gb in each nodes , it is still in yellow state.

When i executed this command `GET /_cluster/allocation/explain`

```
"index" : "***********************************",
"shard" : 4,
"primary" : false,
"current_state" : "unassigned",
"unassigned_info" : {
 "reason" : "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
 "at" : "2020-10-09T16:19:41.803Z",
 "failed_allocation_attempts" : 5,
 "details" : "failed shard on node [f6hB7EYOSR-GiJLFXBn01w]: failed recovery, failure RecoveryFailedException[[******************************][4]: Recovery failed from {70c36ff18063566c3a6089f3d696440a}{*******************}{*************}{di}{di_number=39, zone=us-east-1d, distributed_snapshot_deletion_enabled=true} into {**********************}{****************}{*************}{*****}{*******}{di}{distributed_snapshot_deletion_enabled=true, zone=us-east-1d, di_number=39}]; nested: RemoteTransportException[[****************][*********][internal:index/shard/recovery/start_recovery]]; nested: CircuitBreakingException[[parent] Data too large, data for [<transport_request>] would be [1554462628/1.4gb], which is larger than the limit of [1513521152/1.4gb], real usage: [1554460888/1.4gb], new bytes reserved: [1740/1.6kb], usages [request=0/0b, fielddata=621718551/592.9mb, in_flight_requests=73378/71.6kb, accounting=35794764/34.1mb]]; ",
 "last_allocation_status" : "no_attempt"
}
```

This is what it says. How can i resolve this?

Comment: did you try increasing heap space?

Comment: Yellow status is given by ES cluster when all primary shards has been assigned but some replica shards are still pending to be assigned. Can you try to reduce replica shards?

Comment: @Mohan  Im totally not sure how do i do that can u pls guide me .

Comment: @Harshit , same  i have not done it could you pls guide me

Comment: @RahulRavichandran Please check the AWS Elasticsearch cluster settings. All configurations are present there and you've to tweak them depending on your use-case.

Comment: @RahulRavichandran, i can see circuit breaker exceptions there,  so in the configuration file you can find heap settings, try to increase that.